# Persisting data received in a text file

Tags: java, jpa, mapstruct

I wonder what are approaches to persisting some data to SQL database (I use MariaDB and EclipseLink) in the following situation. I receive as a text file information structured as `key=value` pair. This makes this file easily parsed. The keys are always is the same order and there is a clear pattern. Please have a look at a piece of this file:

> MAX_WM=10
>
> MIN_WP=9
>
> UAM=9
>
> WTR=9

I want information from that file to be saved to database. To do so, I created a `JPA entity` class. No fancy things here, just fields and getters/setters. Here's my question: **in what ways  I could approach setting fields in that entity class?** I could do this manually by reading text file and then using setters. This would be a feasible option as there aren't many keys in the file (up to ten). In the future, it could change thought. Second option that I consider would be using mapping library such as `MapStruct` to done it automatically. I already have `enum` with fields which are the same as keys in the file I receive. However, every example I have seen so far used two classes.

Comment: Your description doesn't give enough information, please provide some code, as well as what kind of database you would like to use.

Comment: I think this is clear even without code. Should I write how I handle this file? How do I use setters?

Comment: Well its hard to give any advice without knowing what are you dealing with. Do you have changing keys or they are always same and known? Will every entry have all keys or some can be omitted? Do you plan on using SQL or NoSQL database? etc.

Comment: OK, now I see your point. I'll update my post.

Comment: From your description what I would do is load that data in some map structure and save it as json, if you really need database MongoDB would be good option.

Comment: MapStruct is just for mapping between objects. You can also map from `Enum` to `Enum`. However, your use case is a bit different

Answer (score 2):

You mention having an enum for the keys.  You can use that to make sure you have a set-method corresponding to every enum value:

```
enum Key { /* ... */ }

Map<Key, Function<MyEntity, Integer>> entitySetMethods =
    new EnumMap<>(Key.class);

entitySetMethods.put(Key.MAX_WM, MyEntity::setMaxWM);
entitySetMethods.put(Key.MIN_WP, MyEntity::setMinWP);
entitySetMethods.put(Key.UAM,    MyEntity::setUAM);
entitySetMethods.put(Key.WTR,    MyEntity::setWTR);

if (!entitySetMethods.keySet().containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(Key.class))) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        "Programmer error: Not every Key is mapped to an entity property!");
}

// ...

Map<Key, Integer> parsedValues = parseKeysAndValues(file);

for (Map.Entry<Key, Integer> entry : parsedValues.entrySet()) {
    Key key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    entitySetMethods.get(key).apply(value);
}
```

The advantages of using method references, instead of reflection, are:

- Their existence, argument types, and return type are checked at compile-time.
- They are faster.
- They can be optimized at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a key-value pair and you know it's fixed then how about using a JSON parser?

Something like this:

```
Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("MyJson.json"));
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
String firstName = (String) jo.get("myValue");
```

or if u have an array then

```
JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("myValues");
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19225615)

Comment: I am new to this ...will follow @petezurich

Answer (score 0):

Without any framework, given that JPA is your ORM, you could read the file line by line and map it inside the entities constructor:

**foo.txt**

```
key=value
```

**FooService.java**

```
EntityManager em;
...

@Transactional
public Collection<FooJpa> save() throws IOException {
   Collection<FooJpa> foos;
   try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("foo.txt"))) {
      foos = lines
        .map(FooJpa::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
   } 
   return em.persist(foos); // returns attached version
}
```

**FooJpa.java**

```
@Entity
public class FooJpa {
   ...
   private final YourEnum key;
   private final YourObject value;

   public FooJpa(String line) {
     String[] rawValues = line.split("=");
     key = yourMapmethod(rawValues[0]);
     value = yourMapmethod2(rawValues[1]);
     ...
   }
```